# mongodb - issue with same file name in fs.files GridFS

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, gridfs

I have multiple files in `fs.files` collection in mongodb GridFS with same name but for different Users.

When I use below query:

```
db.fs.files.find({"metadata.folder" : { "$exists": false,"metadata.msgid" : { "$exists": false}},{"metadata.user":1, "_id":0, "filename":1}).pretty()
```

I get result like :

```
{ "filename" : "standard.wav", "metadata" :
{ "user" : "101" }

}
{ "filename" : "standard.wav", "metadata" :
{ "user" : "100" }

}
{ "filename" : "standard.wav", "metadata" :
{ "user" : "104" }

}
```

Files are different for all Users but having same name.

So when I used following commands to store files in local system for different users, it always store same file for all Users.

For User 101 :

```
mongofiles --uri MONGO_DSN -d test -l /home/user/101/standard.wav get standard.wav
```

For User 100 :

```
mongofiles --uri MONGO_DSN -d test -l /home/user/100/standard.wav get standard.wav
```

For User 104 :

```
mongofiles --uri MONGO_DSN -d test -l /home/user/104/standard.wav get standard.wav
```

It should store different files for different users.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it using `get_id` parameter instead of using `get`.

So my command now :

For User 101 :

```
mongofiles --uri MONGO_DSN -d test -l /home/user/101/standard.wav get_id $object101
```

For User 100 :

```
mongofiles --uri MONGO_DSN -d test -l /home/user/100/standard.wav get_id $object100
```

For User 104 :

```
mongofiles --uri MONGO_DSN -d test -l /home/user/104/standard.wav get_id $object104
```

Here my `$object101`, `$object100`, `$object104` are extended JSON _id of the object in GridFS.

References :

1. [mongofiles: get file by _id in addition to filename](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-618)
2. [MongoFiles](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongofiles/)